# How to take zabbix audit logs to graylog

Tags: zabbix, syslog, graylog

I have a running zabbix server, on which audit logs are visible in UI. I want to take the audit logs to graylog for a centralised logging system.

So far, I have not found how I can achieve this, either I should go for a syslog server in between or is there any plugin available for this.

Example of log is: 2023-09-29 11:33:00 priyanka  User Login 0
Thing is I need to post this on graylog, I already did it in jenkins using audit trail plugin, where jenkins audit logs are send to graylog. But unable to do so with zabbix.
I have not found any plugins which can do so.

If anyone can help will be grateful.

Comment: Can you give some more details? Maybe provide a screenshot of zabbix server UI, and provide an example zabbix log line, and describe the graylog format.  What version of zabbix and graylog?

Comment: Zabbix 5.0.26.

I am not sure of graylog version.

Comment: Example of log is 2023-09-29 11:33:00 priyanka <IP address> User Login 0

Thing is I need to post this on graylog, I already did it in jenkins using audit trail plugin, where jenkins audit logs are send to graylog. But unable to do so with zabbix.

Comment: All of that information should be added to the Question.